# Using @SpanTag to add a custom attribute in traces

Tags: micronaut, opentracing

We are using micronaut tracing for distributed tracing. Which end up in new relic.

We want to add a new attribute/property which to a span, which appears in new relic within a trace. Suppose this property is in `Object`. I figured from the micronaut guide that adding a `@SpanTag` could be solution to it. But, I really do not have any other use of this property in the method, so it makes it an unused parameter. Is there another way?

Existing code:

```java
@NewSpan("foo")
public void foo(Object obj) {
    otherService.bar(obj);
}

// to be
@NewSpan("foo")
public void foo(Object obj, @SpanTag("foo.property") String property) {
    // property argument is not used
    otherService.bar(obj);
}
```

Comment: Seems I can have a resolver, which can extract the value of the tag, which I can simply put on `obj`, but it is not available in micronaut tracing. [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/using.html#using-annotations-custom-extractor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a `Tracer` bean into your class.

```java
import io.opentracing.Tracer;

public Foo {
   private final Tracer tracer;
   public Foo(Tracer tracer) { ... }

   @NewSpan("foo")
   public void foo(Object obj) {
      tracer.activeSpan().setTag("foo.property", property); // <1>
      ...
   }
```

1. Might not 100% correct, but should be close.

Comment: Looks promising, was reading about it, let me test it. Thank you!